# How likely is this mutation?

Tags: code-golf, string, bioinformatics

In my [previous bioinformatics challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194297/mutate-my-dna-sequence), I asked you to mutate a DNA sequence. This time, I'd like you to evaluate how likely a mutation, or a series of mutations, is.

The two types of substitutions are [transitions and transversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversion), and due to the chemical structure of DNA bases, transitions are more likely to occur than transversions. A transition is when a base is turned into one of the same size (purine -> purine or pyrimidine -> pyrimidine), and a transversion involves two bases of different sizes (purine <-> pyrimidine). Following Kimura's model, postulated in 1980, we can define `a` as the probability of a transition occurring for each unit of time, and `b` as the probability of a transversion occurring.

See diagram below. A and G are purines, C and T are pyrimidines.

[image: Graphical presentation of transition vs transversion with probabilities a and b]

Although the exact values of `a` and `b` change from organism to organism (and even between different areas in an organism's genome), we can set `a=0.25` and `b=0.1` for this challenge.

Given two DNA strings of same length as input, I would like you to calculate how likely it would be for string B to be a mutated version of string A. This is code golf, so fewest bytes wins!

Test cases:

```
Input String A | Input string B | Output probability
tgcctatc       | tgcctata       |  0.1
aggttcctt      | gggttcctt      |  0.25
aactgg         | aaccgg         |  0.25
atgccct        | atcgcct        |  0.01
tatcactaag     | tgtcaatgag     |  0.00625
ctcctgggca     | cttttgcgca     |  0.00625
ctgtgtgct      | cagagagca      |  0.0001
atcgctttca     | ttggctttca     |  0.01
attcac         | taagcg         |  0.000001
attttcattg     | attttttacg     |  0.000625
```

Specifications:

- The input DNA strings can be as strings of characters, binary or numerical.
- We will assume that all of the mutations are independent events.
- The output can be in plain notation (0.00015) or scientific (\$1.5\times10^{-4}\$).

If you have any questions or require more specifications, send them my way in the comments!

Comment: For the purpose of questions to self-contain the necessary informations, a brief explanation of what is a transition and a transversion would be welcome

Comment: It's a shame that `P` isn't a base, otherwise we could calculate the chance of `PPCG` mutating to `CGCC`...

Comment: @Kaddath I added a sentence of explanations, but honestly going any deeper than that requires some biochem know-how.

Comment: @Neil you could do that with proteins, given the standard amino acid notation, but that requires adding on another level onto this challenge https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amino_acid#Table_of_standard_amino_acid_abbreviations_and_properties

Comment: @Whitehot I was thinking even simpler, in term of `atgc` replacements, but maybe it's not as simple as that, haven't read the linked article yet

Comment: @Kaddath a transition is a<->g or t<->c, a transversion is everything else. It seemed fairly explicit in the diagram to me, but I can add that if you think it would help.

Comment: @Whitehot yes you're right, I'm just a bit tired and haven't done the link between a <-> α and b <-> β (no excuse, I learnt enough maths for it)

Comment: `tatcactaag | tgtcaatgag | 0.0625` should be corrected to `tatcactaag | tgtcaatgag | 0.00625` and the sixth case should also be 0.00625 and the nineth should be `0.000001` I think since it's 6 `b`s and no `a`s.

Comment: Can I output as a fraction e.g. `1/40`?

Comment: Can you check the 5th and 6th test cases ("tatcactaag | tgtcaatgag " and "ctcctgggca|cttttgcgca")? They're supposed to be 0.625, but I keep getting 0.00625.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite get the probabilities. Take the first test case. There we have `a->c` (0.1) and alternatively `a->t->c` (0.1*0.25=0.025) and `a->g->c` (0.25*0.1=0.025) plus many higher orders. So the total probability should be larger than 0.1+0.025+0.025=0.15. Or you should explicitely exclude higher order mutations.

Comment: I‘ve corrected the fifth and sixth test cases to be more inline with what all the answers are getting, to avoid more confusion

Comment: @Neil output as a fraction is fine, yes

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thank you for the correction, I was very sloppy with the calculations

Comment: "strings of characters, binary or numerical." - does this mean we could choose arbitrary integers or are we limited to the digits 0-9?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I'll allow any arbitrary numbers

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
^ị“½¥¢‘İP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU@xSgNREKz1K8JZCUGfEZPfsLIJEZZFFkIq2SbdJa2dVQptBLWREAsLkTSX5EPyfuQ5uy93Hnj34N3czM7Mju8mk2lKt/ufh1g@VevqtXqJ5WK7uk7AxKK4epeDfiyfp/FzeRPnHzib9/PN232cfZ3uHvffi5SGx8PC1ETELEW34whHVItRF6wKs5KycYdvAnN00glnFzYtkOK3mkAacFD0rkxCrJLNLUWMbLHmyj6OGEto@GABFg4DIskVgDBCUkeE0HcftmAUYDIdOiiMDf3T2XaSE5nE3rbKQ70JHLIZnGpUy7LImrkA7fhvrxAaG5/CfF7PH@JWdy81@gU)

Takes input as `2376` instead of `acgt` respectively. The Footer does this for you

-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan!

### How it works

```
^ị“½¥¢‘İP - Main link. Takes the first input on the left and the second on the right
^         - XOR the corresponding elements
  “½¥¢‘   - Yield [10, 4, 1]
 ị        - Index into this array, 1-indexed and modularly
       İ  - Take the inverse of each
        P - Take the product
```

#### Why this works

| Characters | As integers | `XOR` | 1-index into `[10,4,1]` | Inverse |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `aa` | `2, 2` | \$0\$ | \$1\$ | \$1\$ |
| `cc` | `3, 3` | \$0\$ | \$1\$ | \$1\$ |
| `gg` | `7, 7` | \$0\$ | \$1\$ | \$1\$ |
| `tt` | `6, 6` | \$0\$ | \$1\$ | \$1\$ |
| `ac` | `2, 3` | \$1\$ | \$10\$ | \$0.1\$ |
| `ag` | `2, 7` | \$5\$ | \$4\$ | \$0.25\$ |
| `at` | `2, 6` | \$4\$ | \$10\$ | \$0.1\$ |
| `cg` | `3, 7` | \$4\$ | \$10\$ | \$0.1\$ |
| `ct` | `3, 6` | \$5\$ | \$4\$ | \$0.25\$ |
| `gt` | `7, 6` | \$1\$ | \$10\$ | \$0.1\$ |

Comment: Save a byte by using different digits, e.g. [TIO](https://tio.run/##ZU@xSgNREKz1K8JZCUGfEZPfsLIJEZZFFkIq2SbdJa2dVQptBLWREAsLkTSX5EPyfuQ5uy93Hnj34N3czM7Mju8mk2lKt/ufh1g@VevqtXqJ5WK7uk7AxKK4epeDfiyfp/FzeRPnHzib9/PN232cfZ3uHvffi5SGx8PC1ETELEW34whHVItRF6wKs5KycYdvAnN00glnFzYtkOK3mkAacFD0rkxCrJLNLUWMbLHmyj6OGEto@GABFg4DIskVgDBCUkeE0HcftmAUYDIdOiiMDf3T2XaSE5nE3rbKQ70JHLIZnGpUy7LImrkA7fhvrxAaG5/CfF7PH@JWdy81@gU)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Nice catch, I thought I‘d checked for combinations that didn’t require duplicating the `10`

Comment: So, it appears that there is a tie! Should I accept your answer, as @cairdcoinheringaahing acknowledges that most of their solution is ported from yours?

Comment: @Whitehot If you want to accept an answer, we typically use “first to get that that score” as a tiebreaker metric (which I believe was mine). However, we generally discourage accepting answers at all, because code-golf is best thought of as a competition within each language, so I’m competing against other Jelly answers, rather than every other answer, in order to avoid discouraging people who like golfing in longer languages, such as C# or Java. That said, it’s entirely up to you if you want to accept an answer or not

Comment: thanks for the info, I wasn't aware! I'll leave it open then :)

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>22</s> <s>18</s> <s>16</s> <s>13</s> <s>12</s> <s>10</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
^Tη4ªsèzP
```

-4 bytes by porting [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer (his first version)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/218833/1)
-2 bytes by taking the inputs as lists of codepoints (thanks *@cairdCoinheringaahing*)
-3 bytes by taking the inputs as `[0,1,2,3]` for `agct` respectively
-1 byte thanks to *@cairdCoinheringaahing* by porting [his Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218836/52210) (and now taking `[0,1,2,3]` for `acgt`)
-1 byte thanks to a tip of *@JonathanAllan* (and now taking `[2,3,7,6]` for `acgt`)

Inputs as two lists of integers `[2,3,7,6]` for `acgt` respectively.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/LuTcdpNDq4oPr6gK@P8/2kzHXMdMx1jHCAhBbCMd81guoKgRVNRYxwwsZx4LAA) or [try it online with strings input](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@oYda5rUqJyeklSsaH5z5qWBhcm/A/7uhexcOLHjU1XdhUfHhFVcD//yWJJcmJySWJielcJelAZmJJemI6AA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##PY4xCsJAEEWvErZRIZWKljYeQNAuRBwHGawsHAQFQSw8gDewERFbsRLB9B4iF4l/Jsbd5v/5f97uYknT@axYrXvrzz0Qi4Zmq9vJd6fhtl@Ls2e@v@W7c5K9UnMhqptsRPnhGIXepBiPPo/2@7rMLptBERdJElSYlZRDXEkKaZwEElGFVwTy154QqwjGEAzhM9tl6wJlGJ8aF2UicToMelRusAEBZkIGtIJgpszErvOYxO4vcTq6voWVypSZvWZzPMjVvzxH07/mhyxLvw).

**Explanation:**

```python
^          # Bitwise-XOR the (implicit) input-lists at the same positions together
 T         # Push 10
  η        # Pop and push its prefixes: [1,10]
   4ª      # Append a 4: [1,10,4]
     sè    # Index (0-based modular) the XOR-ed values into this list
       z   # Take 1/v for each
        P  # And take the product of the list
           # (after which the result is output implicitly as result)
```

Here the transformations per pair:

| Character-pair | values | XOR-ed | 0-based index (modulo-3) | indexed into `[1,10,4]` | 1/v |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `aa` | \$2,2\$ | \$0\$ | \$0\$ | \$1\$ | \$1\$ |
| `cc` | \$3,3\$ | \$0\$ | \$0\$ | \$1\$ | \$1\$ |
| `gg` | \$7,7\$ | \$0\$ | \$0\$ | \$1\$ | \$1\$ |
| `tt` | \$6,6\$ | \$0\$ | \$0\$ | \$1\$ | \$1\$ |
| `ac` | \$2,3\$ | \$1\$ | \$1\$ | \$10\$ | \$0.1\$ |
| `ag` | \$2,7\$ | \$5\$ | \$2\$ | \$4\$ | \$0.25\$ |
| `at` | \$2,6\$ | \$4\$ | \$1\$ | \$10\$ | \$0.1\$ |
| `cg` | \$3,7\$ | \$4\$ | \$1\$ | \$10\$ | \$0.1\$ |
| `ct` | \$3,6\$ | \$5\$ | \$2\$ | \$4\$ | \$0.25\$ |
| `gt` | \$7,6\$ | \$1\$ | \$1\$ | \$10\$ | \$0.1\$ |

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##PY4xDsIwDEWvUkViKdmQKia6cAD2qAhjIYuJoRZSmTrBzm2Y4SS9SPh2Ccli@///7EtPx/MpX4c2VNP9WYV2eD/yYb/9jP160Uzjq6lXy3pz2@WYUwoqzErKIZaSQhdTIBFV9ApB/rUrxCqCMQpG4TPLsnmBMoxPjQszkTgdDXw0J9iAADNBA1pBsGbWxL7zmMT@T3E6vJ5CpDSzZttsjoVc7nIdTj/NH5nWfQE) taking input as a list of code points

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing -2 actually, but thanks. :) Is it somewhere in the meta-rules that allows input to be taken as codepoint integers when strings are being asked? I know a list of characters is allowed by default, but I'm never sure about codepoint-integers.

Comment: I assumed that it was ok because of Arnauld's answer, I'm not sure if there are any meta defaults

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Ah, I hadn't even noticed _Arnauld_'s answer took a list of codepoints lol.. I usually golf in Java where characters and codepoint-integers are interchangeable, so falsely assumed for a moment that's what happened in the JS answer, which is obviously not the case. It's probably fine, since doing a manual conversion from characters to codepoint integers doesn't really add much to a challenge anyway, but was just wondering if it's mentioned somewhere in the meta.

Comment: [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/TomRi4VL6XB78eEVVQH//0cb6xjqGOsY6RgAIYhtoGMYywUUNYCKGukYg@UMYwE) (porting my Jelly answer)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks! And that list `[1,10,4,10]` can actually be created 2 bytes shorter in 05AB1E. :)

Comment: I've got to stop helping you outgolfing me :)

Comment: Haha. ;D I indeed noticed we kept outgolfing each other by 1 byte at a time. I see we're tied now, though. :)

Comment: Would it save to use different digits (like 2, 3, 6, and 7)?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks. It was a bit of fiddling around to create the `[1,10,4]` list in a byte less, but I did find something. Just a regular compressed list would have been the same byte-count as the `[1,10,4,10]` list: [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6F7Fw4seNTVd2KTDxXVs66OGBYaGIPbRvcaHNkDFDSyNg@10uELObTc5tErn/38A).

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>52</s>  51 bytes

Expects two lists of codepoints as `(a)(b)`.

```javascript
a=>b=>a.map((c,i)=>p/=!(c^=b[i])|22%c&4||10,p=1)&&p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDBToQwEIbv@xS1iaRNsBSi3srB19isyTBCg1kXsoyeeHecsi3uqvT0lY9//uEdvmDCcz/Sw2l4a5fOLeDqxtVgPmBUCvNeu3os3J3CV9fs@4Oeq@oes8d5Lm0@ulJn2bhQO5FwQkEuGi1cLXA4TcOxNcfBq07tjTEvn13XnhXog77mhlnvdiFASfKIBIRSiFwkAiYtikJYU0YPvCfilySD538oetVTEgHJew5YA5kw0h8xDEOSUST0kaJo0@hQj0MBvFwrMvG3TEm0z1sohlbcDiG4XJB4SqB/XR8OXlZC8OGwuhWwW4W1HWddYjkz0e@uEG4xbR8648321t6kriEcJ9c/sD6AV4uFtss3)

#### How?

Given the code points **p** and **q** of the nucleobase characters, we use the formula:

```
(22 MOD (p XOR q)) AND 4
```

whose result is **4** for a transition pair (`a <-> g` or `c <-> t`) or **0** otherwise. Conveniently, **4** is the inverse of the probability of said transition.

```
 c0  | c1  |  p  |  q  | x = p^q | 22%x | &4
-----+-----+-----+-----+---------+------+----
 'a' | 'a' |  97 |  97 |     0   |  NaN |  0
 'a' | 'c' |  97 |  99 |     2   |    0 |  0
 'a' | 'g' |  97 | 103 |     6   |    4 |  4
 'a' | 't' |  97 | 116 |    21   |    1 |  0
 'c' | 'c' |  99 |  99 |     0   |  NaN |  0
 'c' | 'g' |  99 | 103 |     4   |    2 |  0
 'c' | 't' |  99 | 116 |    23   |   22 |  4
 'g' | 'g' | 103 | 103 |     0   |  NaN |  0
 'g' | 't' | 103 | 116 |    19   |    3 |  0
 't' | 't' | 116 | 116 |     0   |  NaN |  0
```

Comment: Unsure as to why `test("attcac", "taagcg")` gives you such an output of `0.0000010000000000000002`. In theory, the lowest decimal point that can reach is 10^-6, seeing as the sequence is only 6 bases long and only `b` mutations. Could there be an issue in comparing two strings with no characters in common?

Comment: @Whitehot That‘ll be a floating point issue

Comment: @Whitehot Caird is right. Negative powers of ten cannot be represented as exact values in IEEE-754 format. For instance, \$10^{-1}\$ is stored as \$1.600000023841858\times 2^{-4}\$ (the exponent is exact, but the mantissa is approximated). For this challenge, we divide by 10 several times, so there is an accumulation of small consecutive errors which may or may not be visible in the displayed number depending on the final rounding. (We would always get exact results if we had `b=0.125`, which is a power of 2.)

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>77</s> 73 bytes

(input directly as DNA sequence)

```r
function(t,f,`+`=utf8ToInt,d=abs(+t-+f)).1^sum(d>0)*2.5^sum(d%in%c(6,17))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBBb4JAEIXv/gpDY7IrW7KYaHuh9957bhxHmXAQmzok/ff0zSqCUbjMwLffe/DbH/5@jp1Wfd21rM2pdRrqsM23Vaf1@9fps9Wwr2h3drm@5rX3Rfl97o5u/xH9clWsL8uiaRfsNqF88/5qdJkKs5JyFoaRMj9/mceinA0MiajinQKS23yhVusRI1YRMBgYwyNgCWwWBFrYFYljlFWBhkhSISw4RIMrbiY2thqowwQUhRR2W56iYneKZhK7RzBO4lMvmJITwmF56En2OP00VGUZXfe2dBqe9MnpoimMjv0/)

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>53</s> <s>50</s> 48 bytes

(input as vector of `1` for A, `2` for C, `3` for G, `4` for T)

```r
function(t,f,d=(t-f)^2).1^sum(d>0)*2.5^sum(d==4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVQ9b4MwEN37KyK62BVFhiZVF7p37xzpdIFrhpCIPKT@e3oGBtLtDB6Qh@f3dXY/Nr@3y4B6bIeOcb52Dnmbn2qH19YfK1@Ux/twcafP4F@q4jBv6nrvF6Cje3Hu0EjTuwHtx/f1q4PjH@rRu4xYkOVZWb3t9QdhBoEz731ux1HE@d3zLhTlk52dRAA9CFZ6WQNn/uqQIoAYIlZ2RfGM2kIdI2Szc@1KFthMHlKCj5WrdSKxF69I1U4r/@E9KQGODWqTTFYRWjw0vgW5UYTEZS@CSeJ6kBCSypgqVUP2HDSEFXLDPFA8w/4I6PywPPhPTWAyoXbs12H66J8MnYXxDw)

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 34 bytes

```
%@10 4*/@({~(>ag`ct)e.~/:~"1)~:#,.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHBSsQwEIbv@xTDiqSR3WwiroeAuih4Eg8@gcOwjuzFy9yEvnqdSdJUYW1o6U@//PmSnqZ1cB9wl8HBBiJkvbcBnt5enqfLQ4pwc7U7DN/jcI/8TuKPYdzlcZ38mC82YfKrI31@gUPRi/TJWlaTCBK79t2t6svghIkEhRyAki2h8wCwzQAxpJlEZu0kEWck9@Rn8nrfUSRh1spSqok0WeUZ1JYkcQ0VMoPKVjR2AdPUYsSyKWFNOhutuaHxdikms1NLQqPJDoDJ0j8026C6OUK2UeBOLyLFshxwEdFVWurVyfwX3Lzn0zB/@nsa0a4Er48BHn5NOv8HF33zn34A)

### How it works

```
%@10 4*/@({~(>ag`ct)e.~/:~"1)~:#,.
                                ,. join the characters to pairs
                               #   take the ones
                             ~:    where both are different
                       /:~"1       sort the pairs
                    e.~            is it in …
            (>ag`ct)               'ag' or 'ct'?
          {~                       map 0 and 1 to
%@10 4                             0.1 and 0.25
      */@                          fold with multiplication
```

Comment: 26 bytes using integer encoding: `[:*/%@4 10{~1<~:|@-/"1@#,.` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDLTsMwEEX3@YqrIGqKWteBwiIiUgQSK8SCLavRkE6LUFNRdwXqr4exnT4oxIo1Ix/fOfJ7l1szQ1XCYASHUv@xxcPL02P3Wl5OzuspCve1Le625Xc9nuRFfTay3TB7vrfIScA@R7Pk9q1Zg9Z6uwCuMc0iMG8@Vs0nfAva6JY4LJarjc@kspgNLkzMMIOFHWZZw/MWzhaoYLwwe/JsIPuGDIAddXUTMBLxXg995OTQ/QGJvUiktORQHhAXR1IYwylJJ0usjyB3m6KClqYRSS@nrd4l@ZfmIKRiTJFWOa9zYntMJwUlw@olmCSsE7R31QhN6lM1ct/@SnU7PCgnVL35RHXnSj5maFr/CPGjhHc/ "J – Try It Online")

Comment: 28 bytes for current encoding: `[:*/%@10 4{~0=5|1#.3 u:~:#,.` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHBSgMxEIbvfYrBUsaVNibVegiUioIn8eDV0zDYES9expOlr76dyWazFjRhl/3hy59vk8/@IuAethkQlhAh27MK8Pj6/NS/5avrxX2KcPtzjNvNIc3DDXznY54vQ9/N3vnjC5DUBttbEPY1qhILVgBnw8clqjArKSM4WRNhBwCrDBBDGkkSsVJWLZ3SUjeS601DiVVsbyilltiSV/6B@pasWFFlNxjYAY1NwDWtmEiwqFqy1eTNFY13UzG7nVkyOc1@AMKe/qHFJw8/xyQ@C9zoSaRYlhMuIrZLTa06uf@Eu/d4Gu7P56cRfSR4eQiw@7VovMLzG5z03b8/AQ "J – Try It Online")

Comment: 22 bytes with a different integer encoding: `[:*/%@10 4{~0=1#.~:#,.` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNS8NAEIbv@RUvKXat1HVT1EMgIAqexINXD2UY02lF2mKnp0L@epzdpB9Ws2SZIc@885DPNvduhqqEwxgBpb3XHk9vL8/te3l1c/FQBNzumlAVA9@Ug7FvR9nro0dOAtYc9ZJXH/UGtMG0QAFMJ5hkCZnXX@v6G7oCbe3qSCyW661mUnnMhpdpJE5g18CRsLrhwo@yrOb5CsEXqOBUmJWUHeTQkAOwpyZ3ESMRVfuoiZNj9wckVpFEWcmxPCIhraS4hrsk2yypPoHCfRcVtSyNSHo5a22W5F@ao5CJMSXa5NT2pPaU7hSMjKeXYJJ4ztDe1SIsqU@1yEP7KzXs8ajcoebNZ6p7V9KUYWn9T0gPdXj7Aw "J – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 57 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,y:x==[]or[1,.1,.25,.1][x.pop()^y.pop()]*f(x,y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZHRaoNAEEWf9SsW@xANIiYlfQj4JdstTCd1KiQqOgX9ejuzG61QFXbHOXPvXbaf@btrX5faVOZ9qas7PD5vYKZ8vk5VZV032FNeyHe@yOLsVPRdn2Yfc1jdsU6FzRb@GnkUDRvbBJAYABApyY2v5CPmxOXSZUJkYNTecw/SiV5MWZx0mgSV36wAbcWTOF8UAWQK4upC2tx1VRX9uNiow9Yv1UDNRQCAQgSpZARotSjLN6@DaiwBEJSTDCzCWv3j9HQUHBFI3z3lTX0SUQhiorRWKxYgTeYBSYd/5yrLTcZPyXw4nn8Ad9l9KBfHdTcYvRTTtH4dr3HU/jz8HdmDXsqhqJv2lmJmlEUFYSDnK9msgy6O@qFpOa3Towpk2fIL)

Port of my [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218836/66833)

-2 bytes thanks to ovs!

Comment: `x==[]or ... ` saves two bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZHRaoNAEEWf9SsW@xANIiYlfQj4JdstTCd1KiQqOgX9ejuzG61QFXbHOXPvXbaf@btrX5faVOZ9qas7PD5vYKZ8vk5VZV032FNeyHe@yOLsVPRdn2Yfc1jdsU6FzRb@GnkUDRvbBJAYABApyY2v5CPmxOXSZUJkYNTecw/SiV5MWZx0mgSV36wAbcWTOF8UAWQK4upC2tx1VRX9uNiow9Yv1UDNRQCAQgSpZARotSjLN6@DaiwBEJSTDCzCWv3j9HQUHBFI3z3lTX0SUQhiorRWKxYgTeYBSYd/5yrLTcZPyXw4nn8Ad9l9KBfHdTcYvRTTtH4dr3HU/jz8HdmDXsqhqJv2lmJmlEUFYSDnK9msgy6O@qFpOa3Towpk2fIL) (This returns `True` for the empty input, which is allowed by [default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9067/64121))

Comment: @ovs Very nice, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 27 bytes

```
1##&@@1[.1,.25,.1][[#-#2]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU4xbsMwDNzzikICjBaQ3cpFxgQC8oECHQ0PBJEwGZLB4WY4X3eOkm1xII93vNOd9Hq@k96Y5sthjt5XKcWuiaFp96GJfdf52rd9X81/w@2hQMdLSp@nKw3Eeh6eyX83oyNXH3@CY7QYnKC1wSna7/TVV69/psdr3I1OhVlJ2YWPdSY3BTAkooqFGiUbKByiRIzAxJjK1gw46@FoZmVv/jggkpICBCktV2y@8GcyFhEKG0MLK1bFlUmsVi6HQF4ucbaihbXUzCCZtz9mCcTlm/mRsbtpfgM)

Uses `0123` for `acgt`.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>79</s> 71 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

```c
float r;f(a,b,l)int*a,*b;{for(r=1;l--;++a,++b)*a-*b?r/=*a**b-2?10:4:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZPBboMwDIbvPAVCmgQhaFBtl6bRzrvv1nFwopKBWDql3qni2Tuboq4KWyIR5bP1O79lbOWsvVy68QiYBtXlII0ci96jACmMOnfHkAfdqLGqVFmCLEtTCKiEeQmPWoAQptq8NPX2aVur6YIqEQZOh7fjq8fcfkCYr5L00vHgi3OS0mJ1rz9hHI82fxIckL2u5aDmMJdU/Y6w6suy4OugazXsntVA977LWXPft1pn4FKL2X5oC89gqDZXjXDA7@BTr5Ip@YTe50tpflIKAPt232xafYW8zhlSJxDQZpO8o@AcIgUwwmDRuYixgo0SWZFyAaJky6LOOQsxd7xjGVIhRi@BmLP8ijFFpJIznqQx5n/HkaT717FdO7Zu7dhRcerF2jEtZ9eOwfGOMeX@6Zhbad0fjhHB3hzfTRLumlp9BRq6Ls8eqqY5pcu3e/eZ5GHAsmznHmErQ1H89miZW33CQEc@57aFFKB/p/wK5TzFwtwFFkEOqJvi8ofd2JRMlx8)

The function receives two arrays of integers. The bases are mapped as follows

```c
 A  G
-2 -1

 C  T
 1  2
```

This mapping allows the following decision making

```c
*a-*b?r/=*a**b-2?10:4:0;
```

In a nutshell: the product of two bases is 2 only if they have the same size (A<->G or C<->T).

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>8</s>  6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-2 bytes since we may take input mapped from `actg` to arbitrary numbers.

```
^«9‘İP
```

A dyadic Link accepting two lists of integers, `a:4 c:9 t:10 g:7` which yields the probability.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/u0GrLRw0zjmwI@P//f7SJjqWOoYGOeSyICYaxAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##ZZAxTsNAEEVrcoqVqSytwEEBlFvQW440GkWjRKnQNHSm5gIU0CYFTZpU6QgXwRdZ5s/aiSXWLnY8b/7/4/Vys3lJafH9Ne/a95/9U@raD2LRrv1c/R7f6lmcx2kVH5uyPO1uT9vn7vVQplRP6gIYETFLEYNX9opq0cQQwnWobiqch7t7g1WYlZSB9ncy8ArYFGJik/ZZAci56AmXMCuV7AVTQXPUhSr7uNnA4dyvYABzEyCSHMEqGyEZLIagDGMLwATOMqgJo/rHYVnJjkyCZ0y5qScxhSxmSkM1YBlCMgcsHV/28t/XE2BsPq/nh3iU3UM1fw).

#### How?

```
^«9‘İP - Link: a, b               e.g.  [4, 9,10, 7], [4, 4, 4, 4]
^      - bitwise XOR (vectorises)       [0,13,14, 3]
  9    - nine                           9
 «     - minimum                        [0, 9, 9, 3]
   ‘   - increment                      [1,10,10, 4]
    İ  - inverse                        [1, 0.1, 0.25, 0.1]
     P - product                        0.0025
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>10</s> 7 bytes

```
꘍9v∵›ĖΠ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%EA%98%8D9v%E2%88%B5%E2%80%BA%C4%96%CE%A0&inputs=%5B4%2C%209%2C%2010%2C%207%5D%0A%5B4%2C%204%2C%204%2C%204%5D&header=&footer=)

*-3 by porting Jonathan Allan's [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218917/78850)*

### Explained

```
꘍9v∵›ĖΠ
꘍         # Bitwise XOR of the two input lists
 9v∵      # vectorise(min, ^, 9)
    ›     # ^ + 1 (vectorises)
     Ė    # 1 / ^ (vectorises)
      Π   # product(^)
```

Answer (score 2):

### [DESMOS](https://learn.desmos.com/), <sup><s>125</s></sup> 109 bytes

$$f(k,l)=\prod_{n=1}^{\operatorname{length}\left(k\right)}\left\{k-l=0,\left|k-l\right|=2:.25,.1\right\}\left[n\right]$$

```
\prod_{n=1}^{\operatorname{length}\left(k\right)}\left\{k-l=0,\left|k-l\right|=2:.25,.1\right\}\left[n\right]
```

try it online:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6nxdztewy3

Explanation:
\$\prod_{n=1}^{\operatorname{length}\left(k\right)}{}\left[n\right]\$  `takes the product of the list starting with n=1`
\$k-l=0\$ `if k-l = 0 returns 1`
\$\left|k-l\right|=2:.25,.1\$ `else if abs(k-l) = 2 returns 0.25 else return 0.1`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 81 bytes

```perl
sub{$i="@_";$r=1;$_=ord($1^$3),$r/=10-/0/*9-/3|6/*6while$i=~s/(.)(.* )(.)/$2/;$r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDRboIwFIbvfYqO1AkMKGg0cUjm/ZJ5sztxpnbQkakQ6OIWdZd7gD3iXoSdFkSxTXrxnf/85z/Nonw9LHEclMXHao@TQJsuNR/ngefjZZDmrzr2XvDAsHBOAs@1iUvMsU0GhxExR7u3ZB1Bz3dBdMfQHRPBYxDcJ@BwLP1OnOb6hmZzMg93obO4I3xhFdk6ESTcEmsy6fWMfQfBEZwxQQVD1TmcAG0Ach1PSSnnQkBRnCr8GoC0P6y0lAnOEWpcALAWuNDKkUxcaAXjLQBat8ogo4I1pbyJCwAcGiC17qi2ZjIexGS0rkJYAePO4ErO5WXNQoxyeWv1SV5nUTHBrvEC5zY456aSsov15Qrs6j9c98Jb@YBj8yfqUNbaUyVXDZsvHVMLrywcfWZGMMVLv@YI81QEtziuBEbFszzZCkRXhe7ZUkBU38SL7HGnivSACiWKdS19R13bGxb1@/fzq0zDrWZVnnXL/bnFNM2n2TOaPd4gJOd3nXGMEMwI5CDVCRjCHMt/)

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, <s>52</s> 51 bytes

```scala
_.lazyZip(_).map(_.^(_)*7%8/3*7/4*3+1)./:(1.0)(_/_)
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bzvAdRB2SsOz3TQLwJuq9w)

Uses `0123` for `actg`. Like many of the other answers, it xors the values and then hashes them to get the right probabilities.

Here is a table for the XOR, borrowed from Kevin Cruijssen's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218835/95792) (modified for `actg` instead of `acgt`).

| Character pair | values | XOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa | 0,0 | 0 |
| cc | 1,1 | 0 |
| gg | 2,2 | 0 |
| tt | 3,3 | 0 |
| ac | 0,1 | 1 |
| at | 0,2 | 2 |
| ag | 0,3 | 3 |
| ct | 1,2 | 3 |
| cg | 1,3 | 2 |
| gt | 3,2 | 1 |

Basically, we get 0 when there isn't a mutation, 1 or 2 for purine -> pyrimidine or vice versa, or 3 for purine -> purine or pyrimidine -> pyrimidine. The goal is to get 0 to 1, 1 and 2 to 10, and 3 to 4, and then later reduce by dividing these inverses of the probabilities.

| Original value | `*7` | `%8` | `/3` | `*7` | `/4` | `*3` | `+1` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 7 | 7 | 2 | 14 | 3 | 9 | 10 |
| 2 | 14 | 6 | 2 | 14 | 3 | 9 | 10 |
| 3 | 21 | 5 | 1 | 7 | 1 | 3 | 4 |

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>124</s> 72 bytes

```
O$`.
$.%`
¶

L`..
A`(.)\1
%O`.
ag|ct
4
..
10
%`$
$*
¶

~`.+
.+¶1/$$.($&_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3BCgIxDETv@Y6urG6JFvwB74IHr4INQYIXD5Kj@Fn7AftjdVJWcugwM2/6fvjzJaUN47XmdkmVKfFQaZmJzpWZTnXk7a3QcEEk9lGnI8EvBxpqorTr1W/liXha5rJPice0ubfmpurimlchwM0d2rP9FYmom2U8akYSXfUMLCAKHgURwwokcjHSQDGhkjHhYCDhWhxoFYuD13fQQBO1VcKN1RyzGn92F3nu0l3Ufg) Takes input on separate lines but link includes test suite that converts from comma-separated inputs for convenience. Outputs as a fraction `1/n`. Explanation:

```
O$`.
$.%`
¶

L`..
```

Transpose the inputs.

```
A`(.)\1
%O`.
ag|ct
4
..
10
```

Get the probability of each mutation.

```
%`$
$*
¶

~`.+
.+¶1/$$.($&_
```

Take the product and prefix `1/` to the result.

Previous 124-byte solution used decimal output:

```
O$`.
$.%`
¶

L`..
%O`.
(.)\1
1/1
ag|ct
25/100
[a-z].
1/10
+`\d+(.+)¶(\d+)/1
$.(*$2*)$1
{`/1$

^\B
0
(.)(\.(\d+))?/10
.$1$3/1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY2xTgNBDER7f8eetJtbfLdBqZGokVJQckFrGWTRUESugO/KB@THjvEpkQs/jWfG50//@pa2Dvm11/WYOlPiodP1QvTSmWk4QspclkZtaiT2p077w9Tmmd7k4efEoc809uVjzDyW6yWDCryJ8y7tdyU1@u1TS0TvyzPN0ZYX3lzlKbKcWnqc2rq6qbq41hsI/pk72KvdiUTUzSqWmpGEV70iFiGKPAwihhYg7mKkEUWFSkWFIwOEajFIq1gMtK0HDjhhuyHUaK1Rq/FzU3GvG7qL2j8) Takes input on separate lines but link includes test suite that converts from comma-separated inputs for convenience. Explanation:

```
O$`.
$.%`
¶

L`..
```

Transpose the inputs.

```
%O`.
(.)\1
1/1
ag|ct
25/100
[a-z].
1/10
```

Get the probability of each mutation.

```
+`\d+(.+)¶(\d+)/1
$.(*$2*)$1
```

Multiply all of the probabilities together.

```
{`/1$

^\B
0
(.)(\.(\d+))?/10
.$1$3/1
```

Convert the fraction to a decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
Ｉ∕¹ΠＥＥθ⁻℅ι℅§ηκ∨¬ι⎇﹪ι⁶χ⁴
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBCgIxDEX3niLLDERwQNy4Et24qM7CC4S2zARLq5120NPXWvFBwuMnfD1x1IFdKUMUn/DIc8KTLGIs9gRDDCbrhIofbZ4ESnye8RqNeHYoHcHfD@nsjX3hRHDvKt8LXkJqTzcbPcc3qlroAgrBrqb9hmDb/diXwrmi6x5XTXNmPZb14j4) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the RNA translations as input, so expects characters from the set `acgu`. Works with both lower and upper case but not mixed case. Explanation:

```
      θ                 First input
     Ｅ                  Map over characters
         ι              Current character
        ℅               Ordinal
            η           Second input
           §            Character at index
             κ          Current index
          ℅             Ordinal
       ⁻                Subtract
    Ｅ                   Map over ordinal differences
                ι       Current difference
               ¬        Is zero
              ∨         Logical Or
                   ι    Current difference
                  ﹪     Modulo
                    ⁶   Literal `6`
                 ⎇      If nonzero then
                     χ  Predefined variable `10`
                      ⁴ Else literal `4`
   Π                    Take the product
  ¹                     Literal `1`
 ∕                      Divide
Ｉ                       Cast to string
                        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 78 bytes

Accepts input as arrays of integers `[0,1,2,3]`, where `a->0, c->1, g->2, t->3`

```php
function($o,$p){$s=1;foreach($o as$k=>$v){$s/='104'[$p[$k]^$v]?:10;}return$s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJfa4MwFMXf/RRBAlWQNXZ/HuZsnwZ7GKzv4solaJR2GkxaGKWf3d2b2K6sMy/3Jie/c2KiGz2@rHSjg4DXLGdjve@kbfsu4n3CdXzkJk@zuh8qkA3OMTB8my/5gVbm@SwVD7OC64Jvy09@KFfPqchOQ2X3Q8dNdhoz5NrKWIPsImCsCK2S0oKVYcLONYRlwuibz5m4S50MlLIWVy3p1KVxQidbPHodSKsUibCSWE0o9ldHXtLR0Jx8f5VOJ7wvRUMkgPIBscOt4LheJ54mpKRIGE0CSTGdRQ/q/pMqGt5fgqIh4eo0Qkz@LhySPBSJ5@4CPesop9NgVnl7biGumA6BMH989wHt@dVS0pJuSw@VHnpZGbqyGt9B2@m9jfMlDAN8b75AR2Hb2QPsEGbssDF619qIKty5A1lF6BgmIYYL0TB0P7oQSZosknssJ2AcZ8HlXfknAoa5KmZHzF3Jpme8jq4SeWEhyhgxN9NpGeP8@m29ef14z4LT@AM)

**Explanation**

```php
function($o, $p) {        // function accepting two arrays of integers
  $s=1;                   // initial probability
  foreach($o as $k=>$v) { // loop through first input as key, value pairs
    $s /=                 // divide by... and assign result to $s
    '104'                 // string of possible division integers
                          // 1 => no change in probability
                          // 0 => special case
                          // 4 => inverse of 0.25
    [$p[$k] ^ $v]         // take an integer from string offset based on XOR value
                          // of loop's 'value' and corresponding value in second input
    ?:10;                 // evaluate boolean value of integer and return it when "truthy"
                          // else return 10 (inverse of 0.1) when "falsy"
                          // 1) integer is 0 (special case) 
                          // 2) integer is undefined (XOR was 3, string offset doesn't exist)
  }
  return $s;              // return probability
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 53 bytes

```hs
a?b|a==b=1|a/b<0=10|1>0=4
a!b=foldl1(/)$zipWith(?)a b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1BCoMwFET3OcVXBJOFaKTLfj1G1z@piaFRQ82iFO@eil0U2s5qHo9hRlpvg/cpUa82QlQoN6rVuUHZbLJr8MQoU2gWf/WS16J4unBxceS9IFDJwAMQNK3DXhYDJZVQdSAZfKW0h2h/hT5E9WcS36ZlzO4nEwVuBJvIzTuFu5sjFMBtHq3WkaLORfYhykV6AQ)

- input :  `a`-> 1,  `g`-> 2, `c`-> -1, `t` -> -2
- `?` compares bases to get the inverse of probabilities
- `!` zips sequences using ? to compare each pair and folds by dividing